# Unable to create Braintree customer: Processor Declined

Tags: php, laravel, braintree

I have this error, is it related to Braintree configuration or something in code?

This is method for payment.

```
$request->user()->newSubscription('main', $plan->braintree_plan)->create($request->payment_method_nonce);
```

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact 
[support](https://www.braintreepayments.com/contact).</sub>

If you are in a Production account, a processor decline indicates that the customer’s bank has refused the transaction request. Sometimes you can tell why it was declined by reading the response code, but only the customer's bank can confirm the specific reason. You can read the full list of decline response codes in [our Declines documentation](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/transactions/declines#authorization-decline-codes).

In you are testing in a [Sandbox environment](https://sandbox.braintreegateway.com/login), processor declines are triggered by passing a specific [test amount](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/testing/php#test-amounts) that corresponds with a decline code.